# How to import data into GitHub project's view?

Tags: github, github-projects

GitHub Projects provides `Export view data` options that export tasks into a `tsv` file. Does GitHub support reverse option, that is data import from `tsv` file? I'd like to avoid manual work of setting up my project :)

[image: Export view data]

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of writing this post the answer is No. Workaround was to:

1. Create a blueprint file with tasks that I want to create - `blueprint.tsv`
2. Run a seed script to create new items in project - `project-seed.sh`
3. Manually edit tasks in GitHub Porject by editing `table view` - using `ctrl+c`, `ctrl+v`

### Solution

**blueprint.tsv**

```bash
Title   Assignees   Status  Style   Chapter
A       Todo        01
B       Todo        01
C       Todo        01
D       Todo        01
E       Todo        01
```

**project-seed.sh**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Install GitHub CLI https://cli.github.com/manual/installation
# Login with `gh auth login`

function create_fields() {
  echo "Creting project's fields"
  fields=$(head -n1 $2)
  for field in $fields; do
    echo $field
    gh project field-create $1 --owner "@me" --name $field --data-type TEXT
  done
}

function create_items() {
  echo "Create project items"
  titles=$(tail -n +2 $2 | cut -f 1)
  for title in $titles; do
    echo $title
    gh project item-create $1 --owner "@me" --title $title
  done
}

# Static values
PROJECT_NO=2
TSV_PATH=~/Code/github/projects/blueprint.tsv

# Execute functions
create_fields $PROJECT_NO $TSV_PATH
create_items $PROJECT_NO $TSV_PATH
```

**manual edit in table view**

[image: gh-project-table-view-edit]